# loading splash screen takes priority over terminal or windows manager while running elsa

Tags: 12.04, boot, lightdm, plymouth

I recently installed e17 and was trying to set up defaults to use elsa and ecomorph over the standard compiz as it constantly crashes since updating to 12.04. If elsa is installed the loading screen hangs and never loads to login, however i can get to a terminal or the e17 login instead of the standard gdm that usually shows up, within a second the screen goes back to the loading screen. I can still type and login as well as run commands in the terminal, but all I see is the loading screen. Switching between terminals i can confirm my commands before it switches back to the loading screen.  If i remove elsa the loading screen hangs, but I can get to a terminal login and run lightdm to start my session with no problems. I have multiple DE installed and am unsure which loading screen is coming up. i think it's the KDE screen, grub comes up with a debian background if that helps.  I'm not sure if i can switch the loading screen and resolve this issue or if i'm just going to have to scrap using elsa and get lightdm to load on boot again. Elsa would be my preference. I don't have the space to backup my files for a complete reinstall. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I could not get `elsa` to work properly, I was able to get `lightdm` to work properly again with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.